# What are some location services that can be flashed with an Android Pie based ROM?

Tags: location-services

I want some alternative to Google Location service, and I want to use Google Play Store. Any leads are welcome

Answer (score 1):

[MicroG](https://microg.org) should do what you want. As quoted from the website, "A free-as-in-freedom re-implementation of Google’s proprietary Android user space apps and libraries," including a unified network location provider. Simple download and install APK.